# D3.js cannot render my circles from a json file

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

My code is designed to draw simple circles. The data (cx, cy, r and colors) are in a json file. So I would like to extract them to draw, but I get this error : TypeError: e is undefined. Where is my error(s) ? Only the `svg` element appears, but nothing about my circles. I tried to simplify the code, but it seems that my code doesn't read my json file.

Here's my json file :

```
[{
  "jsonCircles": [
   {"cx": 30, "cy": 30, "r": 20, "color" : "red"}, 
   {"cx": 70, "cy": 70, "r": 20, "color" : "red"}, 
   {"cx": 110, "cy": 100, "r": 20, "color" : "red"}
  ]
}]
```

And my code :

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                    .attr("width", 200)
                                    .attr("height", 200);


d3.json("circles.json", function(error, data) {
   if (error) alert(error);

   var myCircles = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data.jsonCircles)
      .enter()
      .append("circle");


var circleAttributes = myCircles
                       .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.cx; })
                       .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.cy; })
                       .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r; })
                       .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; });

});
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: where do you declare `circles`?

Comment: btw. your JSON is invalid - 3rd circle "" instead of "r"

Comment: Also your JSON has "y" instead of "cy" properties for the second and third circle.

Answer (score 0):

```
d3.json("circles.json", function(error, data) {
   if (error) alert(error);
     var myCircles = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
          .data(data.jsonData)//Error number 1
          .enter()
          .append("circle");
    });//Error number 2

var circleAttributes = circles // Error number 3
                       .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.cx; })
                       .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.cy; })
                       .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r; })
                       .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; });
```

**Description For Error Number 1:**

```
d3.json("circles.json". function(error, data){})
```

In the above line data object holds your file data like below format

```
data =     [{
      "jsonCircles": [
       {"cx": 30, "cy": 30, "r": 20, "color" : "red"}, 
       {"cx": 70, "y": 70, "r": 20, "color" : "red"}, 
       {"cx": 110, "y": 100, "": 20, "color" : "red"}
      ]
    }]
```

So in order to point to your circles you need to write it as

```
.data(data.jsonCircles)
```

**Description For Error Number 2:**

Don't close the function there it self, we need to close after all our work is done. Like creating circles, setting attributes, filling colors.

**Description For Error Number 3:**

Here you are using `circles` object, but it depends like have you declared it or not, and as per above code you need to use `myCircles` not `circles`,
And also keep this code inside of `d3.json("circles.json", function(error, data){`
Because we can set the attributes of circles after getting the data only.
Okay

Hope you got it, If not ask me for more.

```
var circleAttributes = circles
                       .attr("cx", **function (d) { return d.cx; }**)
                       .attr("cy", **function (d) { return d.cy; }**)
                       .attr("r", **function (d) { return d.r; }**)
                       .style("fill", **function(d) { return d.color; }**);
```

Above bolded functions(closures) will be invoked the number of JSON Objects/records/rows existed in the `data.jsonCircles` array. And we have written that `d.cx`, `d.cy`, `d.r` to set `cx`, `cy`, `r` attributes of a circle.We need to make sure that all our records/rows are having these attributes.
Okay

To make sure that all our records are having the specific attribute, we can write the code like this

```
function (d) { return d.cx; }
```

add a condition to check whether the attribute is there or not

```
function (d) { 
 if(d.cx){
  return d.cx; 
 }else{
  return 2;//Here we are returning static value
 }
}
```

or we can also write like this

```
function(d, i){
 if(d.cx){
   return d.cx;
 }else{
   return i*2;//See below for description about i
 }
}
```

**Description for i**
`i` is passed by d3, and `i` refer to the index of the record like for first record `i` will hold 0, for second record 1 and so on.

I think you are a beginner and you need to learn a lot more things.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer ! I tried so many possibilities that I let several code mistakes (shame on  me!). Now I corrected them, but have still the mentionned error. I really don't understand why. I wanted to try [this tutorial](https://www.dashingd3js.com/using-json-to-simplify-code), but using a json file.

Comment: Okay, so how do we do this : "...to make sure that all our records/rows are having these attributes" ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. In fact the D3js library didn't load correctly from the url. I added locally the library and now it's working.

Moreover, the brackets around the json data are not necessary.

Thanks to all who helped me!